# Formatting magento timestamp to readable excel format

Tags: excel, magento

I download invoice reports from my magento website. They hold a date format I am not able to change to a standard date format. This is what it looks like: `1 aug. 2016 15:24:08`

What formula can I use to have excel change it to a format like `13-08-16` (Dutch Format) ( I don't need the time for the moment).

Comment: I don't think you need a formula. You can format the cells with CUSTOM specification. That would make Excel interpret correctly the date.

Comment: I think he does need a formula. In excel (if I remember correct) the short name of a month is `aug` not `aug.` and the date is with no space. So `1aug` is a correct date in excel if I remeber correct, typing on my phone at the moment.

Comment: But I think the elephant in the room is how does the 1 aug. Become **13**-08-16 ;-)

Comment: @Andreas.... slippery keyboard... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your 3 letter month names end with a dot in magneto data, you can use this where original data is in cell `A1`

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)+5),".",""),"dd-mm-yy")
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. The date format I provided is exactly how magento reports in the download.... @cyboashu I tried your formula and obviously pointed A1 to where the data actually is from the magento report but does not work I'm afraid. Any other formluas I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Check if *"1 aug. 2016 15:24:08"* is:

a\ pure string (String Type data; "wroted" date)
or 
b\ string representation of Date type data (formatted date)
.

Comment: it seems excel recognizes as date but still unable to change as you would do normally....